# Selecting values in two columns based on conditions in another column (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, conditional-statements

Edit: someone deleted his answer. No idea why since it was useful.

Apologies if this has been asked before, I did not find a solution to help me with this problem.

I have a table that includes different variables, but I'm interested in filtering only certain values given these conditions: in my table, the column "number" begins at 0 until x before it starts from 0 again until another x. For this, I'd like to filter out the lon's and lat's in separate dataframes.
For example, for the first case 0 to 5, I want the lon's and lat's saved as "case 1", then the program should take the next 0 to 4 and print the new associated coordinates to "case 2". This should continue for all cases until the end of the column "number" is reached.

Example of my table:

```
number     lon(geo)     lat(geo)
0    -47     66
1    -45     66
2    -44     67
3    -41     67
4    -38     67
5    -37     67
0    -8      38
1    -7      39
2    -6      39
3    -5      40
4    -5      41
0    .        .
.    .        .
```

I tried setting up the conditions:

```
df = df[(df['number'] >= 0) & (df['number'] <= 0)]
```

Initially, I thought of a loop with some break/next or continue statements inbetween.

```
for i in range(1,len(number)):
    break    

while (float(i) for i in number > 0):
    lon = print (lon)
    lat = print (lat)
    break
```

I'm not sure if this is possible with a "while True" loop? I'm a little confused by this since it's the first time I'm working on such problem so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `for _, group in df.groupby(df["number"].eq(0).cumsum()): print (group)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test1.csv', delimiter=";")
print(df)
```

This is my test CSV (with fake `lon` and `lat` values):

```
    number lon lat
0        0  a0  b0
1        1  a1  b1
2        2  a2  b2
3        3  a3  b3
4        4  a4  b4
5        0  a0  b0
6        1  a1  b1
7        2  a2  b2
8        3  a3  b3
9        4  a4  b4
10       5  a5  b5
11       0  a0  b0
12       1  a1  b1
13       2  a2  b2
14       3  a3  b3
```

I get the position of the zeros and use them in the loop:

```
zeros = df.index[df['number']==0].tolist()

new_dfs = []

for i in range(0,len(zeros)):
    try:
        df_aux = df.iloc[zeros[i]:zeros[i+1]]
    except:
        df_aux = df.iloc[zeros[i]:len(df)]
    
    new_dfs.append(df_aux)
```

What this piece of code does is splitting your DataFrame based on the locations of zeros `(df['number'] == 0)`. You finally get a list of DataFrames, so you can do whatever you want with them.

Comment: Thank you for this, worked just fine on the second try of my data and running fast too :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the zero is the start of each case, then you can loop over each instance of number==0. Make sure that the number column is not also the index of the dataframe.

```
start_idx = df[df.number==0].index
cases = []    
for start,end in zip(start_idx[:-1], start_idx[1:]):
        cases.append(df.iloc[start:end])
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It helped me during a mix-up between number column and index.